# Grabbing multiple data from textbox into textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My code works well for a single-lined input into the textbox. For example: `name:adam`

But what I want is, to grab the name and class when I input data into the textbox. Something like this:

Example:

```
name:adam   
class:8th grade
```

---

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("tarea");
    document.getElementById("name").value = x.value.substring(5);
}
</script>
```

And in the HTML section, I have this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="tarea" onblur="myFunction()"></textarea>


name: <input type="text" id="name"></br>
class: <input type="text" id="class">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should split your textarea based on newlines.  something like

```
function myFunction()
{

var x = document.getElementById("tarea"),
    nameInput = document.getElementById('name'),
    classInput = document.getElementById('class');

var lines = x.value.split('\n');
var name = lines[0].substring(5);
var grade = lines[1].substring(6);

nameInput.value = name;
classInput.value = grade;   

}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVWAD/

Comment: i used the your method here http://jsfiddle.net/irfan/c2LRj/ but didnt get the desired result. please tell me where m i going wrong.

Comment: hey sorry i didnt do the whole thing just selecting the data you needed. udpating my answer with working fiddle and the extra code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming name is always on the first line in the textbox and class is always on the second:

```
function myFunction(){
   var x=document.getElementById("tarea").value;
   var values = x.split("\n");
   document.getElementById('name').value = values[0].substr(5,values[0].length);
   document.getElementById('class').value = values[1].substr(6,values[1].length);
}
```